# Android FAT APK: How to force to use ARMv7

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, armv7

I built FAT APK from hello-gl2 example from NDK examples.
It has 2 folders armeabi and armeabi-v7a

I added following method to it

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_android_gl2jni_GL2JNILib_status(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{
   const char * result = "Hop";
   #ifdef __ARM__
      result = "__ARM__";
   #endif
   #ifdef __ARM_ARCH_5TE__
      result = "__ARM_ARCH_5TE__";
   #endif
   #ifdef __ARM_ARCH_7A__
      result = "__ARM_ARCH_7A__";
   #endif
   return env->NewStringUTF(result);
}
```

When app runs it calls that method and shows returned value in popup dialog.
When I run app on device with ARMv7 CPU I get `__ARM_ARCH_5TE__` message instead of `__ARM_ARCH_7A__`

Then I delete `armeabi` folder in APK and re-install APK. I see `__ARM_ARCH_7A__` message

If I compile `armeabi-v7a` only APK then I see `__ARM_ARCH_7A__` and it does not work on ARMv6 device.

I wish to compile FAT APK that will run `armeabi-v7a` lib on ARMv7 CPU and `armeabi` on ARMv6 CPU.

What I am doing wrong or missing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are getting this Android ICS bug:

- http://www.moodstocks.com/2012/03/20/ice-cream-sandwich-why-native-code-support-sucks/
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ndk/N8FLjvM81pg/2rYeClQZcckJ